# matching space only before character regex and replacing space with dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What I'm after is to replace a space with a dash `-` BUT only if that space is has a character after it. Reason being is I have an array of strings some of which have spaces inserted after the final word or character. (this is out of my control).
e.g 
In the example below I have used %20 to show where a space is 
`string1 = farmer%20jones`
`string2 = farmer%20jim%20`

I have the following regex `preg_replace('/\s./', '-', $string);`

I think I'm half way there, but the above searches for a space preceding a character and replaces that with a `-`

What I get with the above regex is
`string1 = farmer-jones`
`string2 = farmer-jim-`

What I want is:
`string1 = farmer-jones`
`string2 = farmer-jim`

I don't want that trailing `-` to be added.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: It's all possible in one regex, but trimming your values before you apply the current regex would also solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead here:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\h+(?!$)/', '-', $string);
```

- `\h+` will match 1 or more horizontal whitespace.
- `(?!$)` will assert that next position is not end of line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD8vV8/1)